# I am getting error parsing the given value when tried to parse the given json format android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have the below following type of json structure which is coming from url.

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TV",
    "fromcenter": {
        "car": "60 Mins",
        "bus": "20 Mins"
    },
    "location": {
        "latitude": -33.7181,
        "longitude": 10.3160
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Fridge",
    "fromcenter": {
        "car": "30 Mins"
    },
    "location": {
        "latitude": -33.8433,
        "longitude": 11.2411
    }
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mixie",
    "fromcenter": {
        "car": "20 Mins",
        "bus": "40 Mins"
    },
    "location": {
        "latitude": -3.8910,
        "longitude": 11.27777
    }
}]
```

I am able to parse everything except the "bus" because the bus is not available in id 2. So I am getting error as value "bus" not found. JSONException.

Let me know how to solve this? Below is what I tried.

```
try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
        goodModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject e = array.getJSONObject(i);
            spinnerModel = new MyTransport();
            fromcenter = new Fromcenter();
            location = new Location();
            for (int j = 0; j < e.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject object = e.getJSONObject("location");
                latitude = object.getString("latitude");
                longitude = object.getString("longitude");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < e.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject object = e.getJSONObject("fromcenter");
                car = object.getString("car");
                //bus = object.getString("bus"); //I am not able to get the bus. It throws JSONException error.
            }
            spinnerModel.setId(String.valueOf(e.getString("id")));
            spinnerModel.setName(e.getString("name"));
            spinnerModel.setFromcenter(car);
            //spinnerModel.setBus(bus); //I am not able to store the datas.
            spinnerModel.setLocation(latitude);
            spinnerModel.setLocations(longitude);
            goodModelArrayList.add(spinnerModel);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: look at the place where `"id": 2` -> there is no object called `bus`. So provide some dummy value if bus is not present

Comment: instead you should prepare a model class and then use it

Comment: So that's not good suggestion to provide dummy values.

Comment: i am not telling to give dummy values just telling to prepare model class

Comment: you have to check if there is a `bus` key before using it then.

Answer (score 3):

you can interrogate if the object has the property before reading it

```
if (object.has("bus")) {
    bus = object.getString("bus");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward one word.

Use **`optString`** instead of `getString`

`optString` eliminates this issue. Bus is not present in 2nd item.

So use

```
String bus= object.optString("bus");
```